# Is there a good way to reduce value of an attribute via ActiveRecord in Rail4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a column called outstanding balance. And when I get a payment as success I need to reduce the outstanding balance. I could do it explicitly like:

```
Sale.where({}).update_attribute(:outstanding_balance, self.outstanding_balance - payment.amount)

#Rather there should be way like:
Sale.where({}).reduce(:outstanding_balance, payment.amount)
```

Just wondering what should be the best way to do this?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ did understand your comment. sorry

Comment: I meant why do you use while()? Not #all?

Comment: why not just use any after callback?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko my problem is not with where to positing the code, I know how to do a longer version of doing it.. I am just looking for a more better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sale.where({}).decrement(:outstanding_balance, by = payment.amount)

Source: ["decrement" method - RoR v4 API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-decrement)

Comment: I wonder some day if I will stumble on to some requirement that rails cant handle already !! thanks for the answer mate..